# How to get ID from URL in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming, web-deployment-project

I have programming experience from PHP but now I am creating a WordPress theme which is a bit mixture.I have a blog which contains posts , when a user click on a post i want to show the clicked `ID` content in the other page , i am new to wordpress i want to show the details of my each post in the details page.How can i do that ?

> Homepage: Contains a loop for displaying all posts

Now i want a page which display each post separately when a user click any post from homepage.

Comment: read about single.php [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Single_Post_.28single.php.29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be steps below should do it

1. Make `receive.php` as template, add `<?php /* Template Name: theTemplateName */ ?>` at the beginning of template file.
2. Create a page, give it a slug, let say `the-receiver`, make sure you select `theTemplateName` as its template.
3. Now, create a form inside `single.php`, give an (hidden) input with value from `get_the_ID()`, set it POST/GET whatever suits you, and the action to `site_url('/the-receiver')`, match the url to the slug the page that is using your receiver template name. Watch now button should submit the form.
4. Inside the file/template `receiver.php`, do your stuff.